# How to remove the riff headers from wav file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wav, riff

I want to just have the data chunk of the .wav file and exclude all other chunks i.e the riff headers.

```
        let voiceData = try? Data(contentsOf: soundUrl).advanced(by: 44)
```

I did try this but for some reason, there is still some baggage left before the actual audio. could anyone please help me with this issue. if there an efficient way to read the .wav file and only include the data section?

Comment: If you remove the header, it is no longer a wav file. Can you please explain what you are _really_ trying to do? iOS will hand you a PCM version so why do you need to mess with the data?

Comment: The server to which I am sending the audio file does not accept any headers and throws an error if there are any. I know this is a sticky situation but I have no option to strip the headers.

Comment: Well, as I said, you can convert to the raw PCM data easily enough. But if you remove the header, the server won't know how many channels this is, whether they are interleaved, what the bitrate is, etc. etc. etc. What you are asking to do doesn't make sense. The raw sound data with no descriptor is of no use to anything, it will just be a bunch of bytes that can't be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you certain this is actually a WAV file. WAV does typically have 44 bytes of header. Why do you believe there is "some baggage?" How are you determining that?

You can of course parse the RIFF format directly. The easiest (sloppiest) approach is to scan down until you find the bytes "data" (0x64 61 74 61). The next 4 bytes will the the length (in little-endian format, which you can skip if you're just going to read to the end), followed by the actual data you want.

Finding the `data` bytes is done with `range(of:)`

```
let dataBytes = Data([0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61])
if let dataRange = riff.range(of: dataBytes) {
    let start = dataRange.endIndex + 4  // Skip over length bytes
    let samples = riff[start...] // read the rest of the bytes
    // use samples
}
```

Comment: I am really new to swift and was wondering how this exact process could be done. it would be really helpful if you could help me, sir.  I did read through the .wav format and found out that RiffChunkId     = 0x46464952,   // "RIFF"
            WavChunkId      = 0x45564157,   // "WAVE"
            FormatChunkId   = 0x20746D66,   // "fmt "
            DataChunkId     = 0x61746164    // "data"